Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch
I'm playing around with reflection for a class serializer tool.
I'm running into an exception

Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.ThrowTargetParameterCountException()
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at ConsoleApp7.NetworkPacketSerializer.WriteProperty(PropertyInfo property, NetworkPacketWriter writer, Object packet) in /root/ConsoleApp7/ConsoleApp7/NetworkPacketSerializer.cs:line 158

Why is it trying to invoke with parameters?
Here is the code:
var perks = new List<Perk>
{
    new("Test", "requirement.test", true),
};
        
var writer = new PlayerPerksWriter
{
    Perks = perks
};

NetworkPacketSerializer.Serialize(writer);

Here is the writer
public class PlayerPerksWriter
{
    public required List<Perk> Perks { get; init; }
}

Perk class:
public class Perk(string code, string errorMessage, bool allowed)
{
    public string Code { get; set; } = code;
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; } = errorMessage;
    public bool Allowed { get; set; } = allowed;
}

Here is the serializer class:
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp7;

public class NetworkPacketSerializer
{
    private static void AddObjectToWriter(object packet, NetworkPacketWriter writer)
    {
        var properties = packet.GetType().GetProperties();
        
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            WriteProperty(property, writer, packet);
        }
    }
    
    public static NetworkPacketWriter Serialize(object packet)
    {
        var writer = new NetworkPacketWriter();
        AddObjectToWriter(packet, writer);
        return writer;
    }

    private static void WriteStringListPropertyToWriter(List<string> list, NetworkPacketWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteInteger(list.Count);
            
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            writer.WriteString(item);
        }
    }

    private static void WriteArbitraryListPropertyToWriter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, NetworkPacketWriter writer, object packet)
    {
        var collection = (List<object>)propertyInfo.GetValue(packet)!;
        writer.WriteInteger(collection.Count);

        var properties = collection
            .SelectMany(element =>
                element.GetType().GetProperties());
        
        foreach (var elementProperty in properties)
        {
            WriteProperty(elementProperty, writer, packet);
        }
    }
    
    private static void WriteProperty(PropertyInfo property, NetworkPacketWriter writer, object packet)
    {
        var type = property.PropertyType;
        
        if (type == typeof(string))
        {
            WriteType(typeof(string), property.GetValue(packet)!, writer);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            WriteType(typeof(int), property.GetValue(packet)!, writer);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(long))
        {
            WriteType(typeof(long), property.GetValue(packet)!, writer);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(bool))
        {
            WriteType(typeof(bool), property.GetValue(packet)!, writer);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(List<string>))
        {
            var collection = (List<string>)property.GetValue(packet)!;
            WriteStringListPropertyToWriter(collection, writer);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(Dictionary<int, string>))
        {
            var collection = (Dictionary<int, string>)property.GetValue(packet)!;
            
            writer.WriteInteger(collection.Count);
            
            foreach (var (key, value) in collection)
            {
                writer.WriteInteger(key);
                writer.WriteString(value);
            }
        }
        else if (type == typeof(Dictionary<string, int>))
        {
            var collection = (Dictionary<string, int>)property.GetValue(packet)!;
            
            writer.WriteInteger(collection.Count);
            
            foreach (var (key, value) in collection)
            {
                writer.WriteString(key);
                writer.WriteInteger(value);
            }
        }
        else if (type == typeof(Dictionary<string, string>))
        {
            var collection = (Dictionary<string, string>)property.GetValue(packet)!;
            
            writer.WriteInteger(collection.Count);
            
            foreach (var (key, value) in collection)
            {
                writer.WriteString(key);
                writer.WriteString(value);
            }
        }
        else if (type == typeof(List<>))
        {
            WriteArbitraryListPropertyToWriter(property, writer, packet);
        }
        else if (type != typeof(Dictionary<PropertyInfo, Action<NetworkPacketWriter>>) && 
                 type != typeof(Dictionary<PropertyInfo, KeyValuePair<Type, Func<object, object>>>))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{packet.GetType()}");
            AddObjectToWriter(property.GetValue(packet)!, writer);
        }
    }

    private static void WriteType(Type type, object value, NetworkPacketWriter writer)
    {
        if (type == typeof(string))
        {
            writer.WriteString((value as string)!);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            writer.WriteInteger((int)value);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(long))
        {
            writer.WriteLong((long)value);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(bool))
        {
            writer.WriteBool((bool) value);
        }
    }
}


Your error stack says "Line 158" but your posted NetworkPacketSerializer file is only 141 lines long. Could you post the full code, or make it clear on exactly which line the exception is being thrown?
